# No "=" sign in math mode with newtxmath

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath

When I try to produce a `=` sign in math mode using `newtxmath`, I get the following error (using `pdflatex` with TeXLive 2014 on Windows)

> ERROR: Font \csname\endcsname=zxxrl7z at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$=$
\end{document}
```

However, if I remove the `$` signs I get the right output (i.e., a `=` sign, but not in math mode, of course).  Do I need to enable specific options for `newtxmath` to get an `=` sign in math mode?

PS: I have tried including various `ams` packages, such as `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `amsfonts` etc., but the problem persists.

Comment: The `zxxrl7z` font is part of the `boondox` suite that is required by `newtxmath`. In TeX Live it's the `boondox` package, included in `collection-fontextra`. Install it with `tlmgr`

Comment: @egreg: That works, thanks! Would you mind adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `newtxmath` fonts are virtual fonts that use several other freely available fonts. In particular `zxxrl7z` is used by `ntxmia.vf` (composed with pieces from nine fonts) which is the symbol font `lettersA`. The `zxxrl7z` font supplies the double struck letters and digits.

The TeX Live distribution doesn't provide a tree of dependencies, unfortunately. The required font belongs to the TeX Live `boondox` package, which is part of `collection-fontsextra`. Install `boondox` with `tlmgr`

```
tlmgr install boondox
```

or, even better, the whole collection

```
tlmgr install collection-fontsextra
```

Installing the whole TeX Live is usually the best option.

Comment: I believe `collection-fontextra` should be `collection-fontsextra` (note the `s` after `font`): this is the name of the collection in TeXLive 2014. (I cannot submit this as an edit because it is too small in terms of the number of characters).

Comment: You're right, I'll fix it.